# How can you create a row/colspan like this? (Example included for clarity)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want a specific sort of coll span like this C stands for Row/Coll-spanned

```
|-------|
|   | C |
|-------|
| C | C |
|-------|
```

for more clarity this is the code of a simple coll-span and image

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan='2'> </td>
</tr> 
<tr>
 <td></td><td></td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

gives

```
|-------|
| C | C | 
|-------|
|   |   | 
|-------|
```

is this even possible what I want above?

Comment: As Cletus says below, column spans don't work this way. What's your ultimate goal for this? Are you trying to get text to flow around an image?

Answer (score 4):

With row and/or column spanning the cell (merged cells) can only be rectangular. There is no way of creating an L-shaped cell this way. The best you can do is create a 2x2 cell and put something in the top left corner to make it appear like there is an L-shaped cell. This will have one major problem: there's no way to tie the width of this inner block to the width of the column it's supposedly in. Fixing the width of the column and this block will mostly solve this problem.