# HTML/CSS: L-Shaped Cell in Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is it possible, using HTML and/or CSS, to create a table with an L-shaped cell? [The only way I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660616/html-how-can-you-create-a-row-collspan-like-this-example-included-for-clearit) doesn't actually make the cell L-shaped (though it does make it look like one).

For example, in a table with the following cells:

```
| 00 | 01 | 02 | 03 |
| 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 |
| 20 | 21 | 22 | 23 |
| 30 | 31 | 32 | 33 |
```

The goal is to make a cell that takes the place of cells 11, 12, and 21, without shifting cell 22 out of the way.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I'm with @Krumia with this. Tables should be for tabular data, and I find it unusual that data would need to be presented in an L-shape. Can you add some more context for this?

Comment: @user764357 consonant inventory table.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do this.

However, you can make it *look like* it with few CSS styles:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/az9cvj5g/2/).

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid navy;
    padding: 5px;
}

.nobordertop { border-top: none; }
.noborderbottom { border-bottom: none; }
.noborderleft { border-left: none; }
.noborderright { border-right: none; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>02</td>
        <td>03</td>
        <td>04</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td class="noborderright noborderbottom">12</td>
        <td class="noborderleft">13</td>
        <td>14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>21</td>
        <td class="nobordertop">22</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>34</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

#### Result:

[image: Result of HTML and CSS displaying an L-shaped area]